# Evaluate per class precision and recall in FastText

Tags: machine-learning, precision-recall, fasttext

I am using Facebook Research FastText library for text classification following [this](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/supervised-tutorial.html) tutorial. I have 2 labels for which i am performing the classification (2-class). The output of the prediction on test file shows the precision and recall for the same. How can i calculate per-class precision and recall for my test file?

Comment: why not using the one from sklearn: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_precision_recall.html

Answer (score 1):

I had to deal with this recently myself. This [issue in Github](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/issues/261) describes the issue, and presents a [solution](https://gist.github.com/loretoparisi/41b918add11893d761d0ec12a3a4e1aa).

In summary, you need to do this as a post processing step. The code linked to above does a comparison of your actual labels vs the predicted ones and computes a confusion matrix which accurately reflects the classifier's performance for binary classification. This code computes the confusion matrix and accuracy only. If you wanted to also add in the precision and recall you could similarly use the scikitlearn API such as `sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_fscore_support`